# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 / 4.11.3 kernel / rtl8812au won't connect

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.04, realtek, alfa-wireless

New PC, never had WiFi working on it before.  Ethernet works fine.  Trying to use Alfa AWUS036AC which uses RLT8812AU.  Initially tried to update driver with **Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** in Gnome, didn't work, no response from adapter.  Went searching and found info about adding:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

to `NetworkManager.conf` but that didn't work.  Uninstalled the rlt8812au-dkms driver and installed the one from https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au and now I can see the WiFi adapter using tools like iwconfig, lsusb, etc. and it shows in the system center, giving me the ability to turn it on/off, connect, etc.

The only problem is - it never connects, it tries but fails repeatedly.  I monitored Network Manager and found that there was an error setting powersave 1 and I searched and found something to address that (`sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`) but now I get error setting powersave 0.  I don't know if the command I ran made things better or worse but that appears to be my only error while trying to connect.

I ran the network troubleshooting script and have it pastebinned for someone to look at @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/24798045/

Hopefully I didn't leave anything out - I'm new and frustrated and ready to move on to the next issue once this one is resolved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to an unsupported kernel.

Comment: Do you have the same issue running the stock Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6 so? The OP is using Ubuntu, they've just installed a newer kernel. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6190/85695

Comment: I know that. We do not support unreleased Ubuntu, why should we support issues with unsupported kernels? If OP used 17.10 it would be off-topic... The answer is that the driver has not been patched yet for that kernel. It will be when the kernel will be supported in Ubuntu most likely.

Comment: @terdon I wrote my answer at meta.

Comment: @Zanna - Yes, same issue running 4.10.22.23/24.

Comment: In fact, the reason I installed 4.11.3 was hoping a newer kernel would address the issue. I didn't realize installing it would exclude me from asking for help. I'll put it back to generic and then come back and ask the same question again if that's necessary.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm running 17.04 with kernel version 4.13.0-38 and have the same issue.

Comment: https://files.alfa.com.tw/?dir=%5B1%5D%20WiFi%20USB%20adapter/AWUS036ACH/Linux     can somebody explain how to install this tar file?